# ArrayList and Arrays.asList works differently for Collection in case of inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

```
public class SS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SS s = new SS();
        List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

        s.checkWithoutInheritance(Arrays.asList(new B()));  //Works fine
        s.checkWithoutInheritance(list);    //----------Not working

        s.checkWithInheritance(Arrays.asList(new B())); //Works fine
        s.checkWithInheritance(list);   //Works fine
    }

    private void checkWithInheritance(final Collection<? extends A> s) {
    }

    private void checkWithoutInheritance(final Collection<A> s) {
    }
}


class A {
};

class B extends A {
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a method:

```
void checkWithoutInheritance(final Collection<A> s);
```

The line:

```
s.checkWithoutInheritance(Arrays.asList(new B()));
```

works fine, because it's the same as:

```
List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new B());
s.checkWithoutInheritance(list);
```

But, the following code:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<B>();
s.checkWithoutInheritance(list); // compiler error
```

produces a compiler error, because generics [are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po), and `List<B>` can not be assigned to the `List<A>`:

```
List<B> listb = new ArrayList<B>();
List<A> lista = listb; // Incompatible types error, even though B extends A
```

---

When you have a method:

```
void checkWithInheritance(final Collection<? extends A> s);
```

`<? extends A>` [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) relax the restrictions on the variable `s`, therefore both are valid:

```
s.checkWithInheritance(new ArrayList<A>());
s.checkWithInheritance(new ArrayList<B>());
```

`<? extends A>` works on lists of `A` and the subtypes of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

They don't behave differently, you are using them differently.

Here you are letting the compiler decide the type of the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList`, and the compiler decides it should be `List<A>`, given the argument required by `checkWithoutInheritance()`:

```
s.checkWithoutInheritance(Arrays.asList(new B()));
```

Here you are passing a `List<B>` to the method, so the compiler has no choice but to fail:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
s.checkWithoutInheritance(list);
```

If you used both `List`s the same you'd get the same output:

Both failing:

```
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<B> list2 = Arrays.asList(new B());
s.checkWithoutInheritance(list2); 
s.checkWithoutInheritance(list);
```

Both working:

```
s.checkWithoutInheritance(Arrays.asList(new B()));
s.checkWithoutInheritance(new ArrayList<>());
```

As for `checkWithInheritance(final Collection<? extends A> s)`, it accepts both a `List<A>` and a `List<B>`, which is why both of your `checkWithInheritance` calls pass compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<B> list;
```

This declares a variable which is a list, with the guarantee that everything in that list is something that can be cast `B` (i.e. `B`, a subclass of `B`, or `null), to which you can only add things which can be cast to`B`.

```
private void checkWithoutInheritance(final Collection<A> s) {
```

This declares a method, accepting a parameter which is a collection, with the guarantee that everything in that collection can be cast to `A`, to which you can only add things which can be cast to `A`.

This means that `checkWithoutInheritance` can do this:

```
s.add(new A());
```

If you were able to call

```
checkWithoutInheritance(list);
```

then `list` would now contain an instance of `A`, which cannot be cast to a `B`, violating the guarantee on the contents of `list`.

As such, it is disallowed by the compiler. The compiler doesn't care that you *don't* add an `A` to `s`, because you *could*. It errs on the side of safety.

---

On the other hand:

```
private void checkWithInheritance(final Collection<? extends A> s) {
```

This declares a method, accepting a parameter which is a collection, with the guarantee that everything in that collection is something which can be cast to *some subclass of `A`*.

You can't add an `A` to it, because you don't know if "some subclass" means `A`, `B`, or something else entirely.

As such, you can't write `s.add(new A());` in its method body, so it is safe to pass a `List<B>` to it.